# Delphi Script (Changing Section Name for VMProtect)

Tags: delphi

I don't know Delphi and would someone help me to change a small Delhpi script from vmprotect?

```
function GetRandomSectionName: String;
var I:Integer;
    B:Byte;
begin
  Result:='';
  for I:=1 to 8 do
   begin
    B:=32+Random(Ord('z')-32);
    Result:=Result+Chr(B);
   end; 
end;

procedure OnAfterSaveFile;
var I:Integer;
begin
  with VMProtector.OutputFile do
   for I:=0 to Sections.Count-1 do
    Sections.Items[I].Name:=GetRandomSectionName;
end;
```

It should only randomize the sections which is starting with .vmp the rest should stay.

Answer (score 1):

> It should only randomize the sections which is starting with .vmp the rest should stay.

Use the [System.Pos](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Pos) function to match a substring in a string.

```
procedure OnAfterSaveFile;
var I:Integer;
begin
  with VMProtector.OutputFile do
   for I:=0 to Sections.Count-1 do
     if Pos('.vmp',Sections.Items[I].Name) = 1 then // Only .vmp sections
       Sections.Items[I].Name:=GetRandomSectionName;
end;
```